# How can I access to static class members using $this?

Tags: php, oop, laravel, reference, static-members

I'm trying to access static class members of a ActiveModel class in another class.

```
$class = "\ActiveModel\User";
$class::create(); //WORKS!

$this->class = "\ActiveModel\User";
$this->class::create(); //DOESN'T WORK :( - Throws "Incorrect access to static class member" error
```

What is the correct way to access it with `$this->var`?

**Another example:**
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The PHP language forbids this kind of construction. There are other examples. (e.g. previously, you cannot direct access an array returned by a function)

```
$elem = get_array()[0] // Doesn't work until PHP 5.4.0
```

The main reason behind these limitations is that the parser doesn't like it. Because they are complex, or causes ambiguity, or they want to reserve such constructions for future use.

You can simply workaround this restriction by assigning a temporary variable:

```
$className = $this->class;
$className::create(); // This will work.
```

Comment: yes, that's what i've been doing so far.. but it seems like a bit redundant to extract the variable into another (but reading adrian's reply, I guess that's the only way to do it right now)

Comment: `($this->class)::create()`

Answer (score 2):

Because PHP does not support that kind of evaluation <del>prior to 5.6.2</del> (Seems like newer versions still not support it).

If you truly have to do it no matter what, use `call_user_func()` or `call_user_func_array()` like this:

```
call_user_func_array(
    array(
        $this->modalClassName, 
        'create'
    ), 
    array()
);
```

and add a `setHasMany` method for your modal class by using

```
call_user_func_array(
    array(
        $this->modalClassName, 
        'setHasMany'
    ), 
    array(['user_level'])
);
```

instead of directly setting the `$hasmany` variable.

I would not recommend it though. You may try something like **Dependency Injection** for cases like this.

Comment: thanks but i think it's easier to just extract it back to a variable and use that.. still it's good to TIMTOWTDI

Comment: Yeah, the back-to-local-variable way is good too, and it's appear to be more faster than call_user_func_* :)